# AngularJS, Foundation - navigation downtown ng-click not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, zurb-foundation-5

For some reason my `ng-click` directive is not being called on dropdown menus using AngularJS, Foundation and the [Angular Foundation](http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/) library.  Clicking on links does not work, but I am currently more concerned with `ng-click` working.

In the code below, clicking the link *TOP-LEVEL* works on the navigation bar.  However, when you click the username and the dropdown appears, clicking the *Logout* link that appears does nothing.  No warnings in the console or anything.

The app is set on the root HTML element:

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="MyApplication">
```

The controller is set on the body tag:

```
<body data-ng-controller="MyRootController">
```

### HTML

```
<nav class="top-bar hide-for-small-only" role="navigation" data-options="sticky_on: large" data-topbar>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#">My Application</a></h1>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="right">

      <li data-ng-hide="userLoggedIn">
        <a href="#" data-ng-click="openLoginPopup()"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" data-ng-click="logoutOfSystem()">TOP-LEVEL</a>
      </li>

      <li class="has-dropdown" data-ng-show="userLoggedIn">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ user.Username }}</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Some drop-down option...</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-ng-click="logoutOfSystem()"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

### JavaScript

```
angular.module('MyApplication').controller('MyRootController', [
  '$scope', 'LoginService',
  function ($scope, LoginService) {
    // ...
    $scope.logoutOfSystem = function () {
      var justReload = function () { window.location.reload(); };
      LoginService.logout().then(justReload, justReload);
    };
    // ...
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
  <li class="has-dropdown" data-ng-show="userLoggedIn">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ user.Username }}</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Some drop-down option...</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-ng-click="logoutOfSystem()"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

to:

```
  <li has-dropdown data-ng-show="userLoggedIn">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ user.Username }}</a>
    <ul top-bar-dropdown>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Some drop-down option...</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-ng-click="logoutOfSystem()"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

You have to use directives instead of manually setting the class.

Atleast this worked for me, i hope it works for you to!

Navles